# R rtweet search_30day message: Exceeded rate limit

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I want to search for any instance of several different hashtag uses from two weeks ago. I went with `search_30day()` to do so. I expect there to be around 100,000(ish) tweets that I then want to do sentiment analysis later. However, I run the following, and after it hit's 2%, it says that `2%list(message="Exceeded rate limit"...)`. Is there a way to pick up where I left on on the search once Twitter's 15-min window resets?

```
myTweets <- search_30day("#generalconference OR #conference", n=100000, fromDate="2019-10-04, toDate="2019-10-07",env_name="ConfData", parse=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: the best solution I came up with is to create a loop  where after 3000 tweets have been pulled, I put the system to sleep for 15 min until the 15 min window clears and I keep going.